# I can't see databases after restore content of folder /var/lib/mysql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-20.04

Maybe it will a duplicate topic but after two days of googling and trying a lot of settings combinaton i need help with my MySQL server...

My MySQL server is accidentally died but i have stored all data from folder `/var/lib/mysql`.

Before a clean install of MySQL server i cleared all content from folder `/var/lib/mysql`.
[According to the these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964417/is-it-possible-to-restore-a-mysql-database-from-the-var-lib-mysql-database-fold) after install MySQL i copied *database folders (and all their content) back to /var/lib/mysql. Then also copy ib(asterisk) to /var/lib/mysql as well)*.
And after this i setting chown to `mysql:mysql` and i restarted a server.
But after restart i can see only "default" databases and i cann't see my DB.

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please, what am i doing wrong? Is possible to full "restore" databases from data from folder `/var/lib/mysql`

If yes, please how?

My server isn't working and i can't do sqldump :/

```
mysql -V
mysql  Ver 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

Thank you for any ideas...

#### Update: List of my steps

It is really serious problem for me and for sure i write here all steps which i do:

1. complete backup of folder `/var/log/mysql`
2. uninstall all with `apt --purge remove mysql-*`
3. delete all files with:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
sudo rm -rf /var/log/mysql
```

4. install `apt install mysql-server`
5. create mysql user `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'xxxx';`
6. stop mysql server `systemctl stop mysql.service`
7. copy files:

```
mkdir /var/lib/mysql/test_db1
cp -Rv db_backup/mysql/test_db1/* /var/lib/mysql/test_db1/
cp -Rv db_backup/mysql/ib* /var/lib/mysql/
```

8. change owner to mysql with command

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

9. Add these rows

```
[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = 4
```

to file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

10. start server with `systemctl start mysql.service`
11. log with `sudo lnav /var/log/mysql/error.log`

```
[sudo] password for xxxxxxx: 
2020-09-21T06:43:04.044711Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4) initializing of server in progress as process 3474
2020-09-21T06:43:04.055166Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-09-21T06:43:04.796495Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-09-21T06:43:06.353841Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
2020-09-21T06:43:07.931371Z 6 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user boot. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4).
2020-09-21T06:43:11.425181Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4) starting as process 3531
2020-09-21T06:43:11.473322Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-09-21T06:43:11.917313Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-09-21T06:43:12.154931Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011292] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Preparation of I/O interfaces failed, X Protocol won't be accessible'
2020-09-21T06:43:12.156589Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011300] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Setup of socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' failed, can't create lock file /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock.lock'
2020-09-21T06:43:12.369358Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-09-21T06:43:12.369606Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2020-09-21T06:43:12.375351Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/tmp' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2020-09-21T06:43:12.417636Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4'  socket: '/tmp/tmp.MdU5Jvz6dw/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  (Ubuntu).
2020-09-21T06:43:12.570511Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4).
2020-09-21T06:43:14.014132Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4)  (Ubuntu).
2020-09-21T06:43:15.325632Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4) starting as process 3600
2020-09-21T06:43:15.356322Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-09-21T06:43:15.710982Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-09-21T06:43:15.909195Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011300] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Setup of socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' failed, can't create lock file /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock.lock'
2020-09-21T06:43:15.909589Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2020-09-21T06:43:16.117225Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-09-21T06:43:16.117469Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2020-09-21T06:43:16.126169Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/tmp' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2020-09-21T06:43:16.176374Z 7 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user boot. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4).
2020-09-21T06:43:18.426002Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4)  (Ubuntu).
2020-09-21T06:43:20.526272Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4) starting as process 3769
2020-09-21T06:43:20.536771Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-09-21T06:43:20.970922Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-09-21T06:43:21.276105Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2020-09-21T06:43:21.439577Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-09-21T06:43:21.439841Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2020-09-21T06:43:21.488037Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
2020-09-21T06:46:03.582451Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4).
2020-09-21T06:46:06.519055Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4)  (Ubuntu).
2020-09-21T07:02:45.464610Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4) starting as process 775
2020-09-21T07:02:45.631164Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-09-21T07:02:47.973692Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-09-21T07:02:49.148633Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2020-09-21T07:02:49.666907Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-09-21T07:02:49.670219Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2020-09-21T07:02:49.893631Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
2020-09-21T07:17:42.508256Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4).
2020-09-21T07:17:44.780217Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4)  (Ubuntu).
2020-09-21T07:28:58.520769Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4) starting as process 1443
2020-09-21T07:28:58.550931Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-09-21T07:28:59.004925Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-09-21T07:28:59.210887Z 1 [Warning] [MY-010005] [Server] Skip re-populating collations and character sets tables in InnoDB read-only mode.
2020-09-21T07:28:59.243529Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2020-09-21T07:28:59.244407Z 2 [Warning] [MY-011018] [Server] Skip updating information_schema metadata in InnoDB read-only mode.
2020-09-21T07:28:59.246569Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010970] [Server] Skipped updating resource group metadata in InnoDB read only mode.
2020-09-21T07:28:59.246712Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010970] [Server] Skipped updating resource group metadata in InnoDB read only mode.
2020-09-21T07:28:59.304228Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-09-21T07:28:59.304477Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2020-09-21T07:28:59.359899Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
2020-09-21T11:42:53.341383Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4).
2020-09-21T11:42:54.999842Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4)  (Ubuntu).
2020-09-21T11:44:42.649789Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4) starting as process 773
2020-09-21T11:44:42.751076Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-09-21T11:44:44.618159Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-09-21T11:44:45.687042Z 1 [Warning] [MY-010005] [Server] Skip re-populating collations and character sets tables in InnoDB read-only mode.
2020-09-21T11:44:45.745974Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2020-09-21T11:44:45.750371Z 2 [Warning] [MY-011018] [Server] Skip updating information_schema metadata in InnoDB read-only mode.
2020-09-21T11:44:45.767617Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010970] [Server] Skipped updating resource group metadata in InnoDB read only mode.
2020-09-21T11:44:45.767836Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010970] [Server] Skipped updating resource group metadata in InnoDB read only mode.
2020-09-21T11:44:46.019318Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-09-21T11:44:46.019570Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2020-09-21T11:44:46.220355Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
```

12. check database in DBeaver and i see only:

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

### Update 2: Output of show global variables

```
mysql> show global variables like '%dir%';
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name                           | Value                      |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------------+
| basedir                                 | /usr/                      |
| binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates | OFF                        |
| character_sets_dir                      | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
| datadir                                 | /var/lib/mysql/            |
| innodb_data_home_dir                    |                            |
| innodb_directories                      |                            |
| innodb_doublewrite_dir                  |                            |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir               | ./                         |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct              | 90.000000                  |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm          | 10.000000                  |
| innodb_redo_log_archive_dirs            |                            |
| innodb_temp_tablespaces_dir             | ./#innodb_temp/            |
| innodb_tmpdir                           |                            |
| innodb_undo_directory                   | ./                         |
| lc_messages_dir                         | /usr/share/mysql/          |
| plugin_dir                              | /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/     |
| slave_load_tmpdir                       | /tmp                       |
| tmpdir                                  | /tmp                       |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------------+
18 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

### Update 3: error log after copy entire folder /var/lib/mysql

In this attempt was in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` added

```
[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = 4
```

and in next attemps was used value 5, 6. Output of log was same.

```
sudo cat /var/log/mysql/error.log
2020-09-22T07:46:22.739869Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4) starting as process 2624
2020-09-22T07:46:22.753948Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-09-22T07:46:23.150836Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-09-22T07:46:23.153580Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011096] [Server] No data dictionary version number found.
2020-09-22T07:46:23.153802Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2020-09-22T07:46:23.154040Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-09-22T07:46:23.665236Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4)  (Ubuntu).
2020-09-22T07:46:24.159762Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4) starting as process 2650
2020-09-22T07:46:24.173618Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-09-22T07:46:24.561326Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-09-22T07:46:24.564213Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011096] [Server] No data dictionary version number found.
2020-09-22T07:46:27.556958Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-09-22T07:46:28.067684Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4)  (Ubuntu).
2020-09-22T07:46:28.652845Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4) starting as process 2710
2020-09-22T07:46:28.670270Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-09-22T07:46:29.054648Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-09-22T07:46:29.057477Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011096] [Server] No data dictionary version number found.
2020-09-22T07:46:29.057705Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2020-09-22T07:46:29.057912Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-09-22T07:46:29.568544Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4)  (Ubuntu)
```

### Update 4: Restored "older" version of server with same version of MySQL

When i copied only db folder and files `ib*` after start of MySLQ, i don't saw any errors in log but in DBeaver i don't saw my restored DB (only "default" databases).

When i copied full folder `/var/lib/mysql` after start of server, terminal shown:

```
sudo systemctl start mysql.service 
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

and in `sudo lnav /var/log/mysql/error.log` was logged errors.

Full log:

```
2020-05-08T18:30:05.405899Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) initializing of server in progress as process 3730
2020-05-08T18:30:05.415536Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-05-08T18:30:10.973980Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-05-08T18:30:19.418435Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
2020-05-08T18:30:29.248033Z 6 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user boot. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1).
2020-05-08T18:30:39.563577Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 3784
2020-05-08T18:30:39.609342Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-05-08T18:30:40.825826Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-05-08T18:30:41.069690Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011292] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Preparation of I/O interfaces failed, X Protocol won't be accessible'
2020-05-08T18:30:41.070005Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011300] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Setup of socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' failed, can't create lock file /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock.lock'
2020-05-08T18:30:41.562105Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-05-08T18:30:41.570251Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/tmp' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2020-05-08T18:30:41.597449Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1'  socket: '/tmp/tmp.tPMiFvGi8X/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  (Ubuntu).
2020-05-08T18:30:44.447698Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2020-05-08T18:30:45.523547Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 3855
2020-05-08T18:30:45.533828Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-05-08T18:30:46.312690Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-05-08T18:30:46.461804Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011300] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Setup of socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' failed, can't create lock file /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock.lock'
2020-05-08T18:30:46.462073Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2020-05-08T18:30:46.789266Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-05-08T18:30:46.798154Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/tmp' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2020-05-08T18:30:46.841228Z 7 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user boot. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1).
2020-05-08T18:30:48.523578Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2020-05-08T18:30:50.775196Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 4024
2020-05-08T18:30:50.784578Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-05-08T18:30:51.773989Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-05-08T18:30:51.925901Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2020-05-08T18:30:52.076910Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-05-08T18:30:52.103666Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
2020-09-23T13:34:43.685315Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 844
2020-09-23T13:34:43.774085Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-09-23T13:34:45.075312Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-09-23T13:34:45.386676Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2020-09-23T13:34:45.440758Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
2020-09-23T13:34:45.513241Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
2020-09-23T13:34:45.740429Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-09-23T13:34:45.803306Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
2020-09-23T13:55:41.660814Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 9  user: 'dataintegra'.
2020-09-23T13:55:42.751286Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2020-09-23T13:57:03.148302Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 2646
2020-09-23T13:57:03.160530Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-09-23T13:57:03.175203Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012197] [InnoDB] Unable to open './pharmiseu/visitscalendar.ibd'
2020-09-23T13:57:03.175349Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012197] [InnoDB] Unable to open './pharmiseu/specializations_prim.ibd'
2020-09-23T13:57:03.175460Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012197] [InnoDB] Unable to open './pharmiseu/visitscalendar_manager.ibd'
2020-09-23T13:57:03.175870Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012197] [InnoDB] Unable to open './pharmiseu/roles.ibd'
2020-09-23T13:57:03.176006Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012197] [InnoDB] Unable to open './pharmiseu/direct_orders_products.ibd'
2020-09-23T13:57:03.176139Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012197] [InnoDB] Unable to open './pharmiseu/companies.ibd'
2020-09-23T13:57:03.176281Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012197] [InnoDB] Unable to open './pharmiseu/specializations_sec.ibd'
2020-09-23T13:57:03.176468Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012197] [InnoDB] Unable to open './pharmiseu/targetings.ibd'
2020-09-23T13:57:03.177021Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012197] [InnoDB] Unable to open './pharmiseu/districts.ibd'
2020-09-23T13:57:03.177219Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012197] [InnoDB] Unable to open './pharmiseu/alembic_version.ibd'
2020-09-23T13:57:03.177451Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012197] [InnoDB] Unable to open './pharmiseu/subject_types.ibd'
2020-09-23T13:57:03.177650Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012197] [InnoDB] Unable to open './pharmiseu/users.ibd'
2020-09-23T13:57:03.177857Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012197] [InnoDB] Unable to open './pharmiseu/settings.ibd'
2020-09-23T13:57:03.178071Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012197] [InnoDB] Unable to open './pharmiseu/reports.ibd'
2020-09-23T13:57:03.178288Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012197] [InnoDB] Unable to open './pharmiseu/subjects.ibd'
2020-09-23T13:57:03.178529Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012197] [InnoDB] Unable to open './pharmiseu/targetings_of_subjects.ibd'
2020-09-23T13:57:03.178774Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012197] [InnoDB] Unable to open './pharmiseu/report_products_association.ibd'
2020-09-23T13:57:03.179090Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012197] [InnoDB] Unable to open './pharmiseu/promo_products.ibd'
2020-09-23T13:57:03.708748Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-09-23T13:57:04.043407Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2020-09-23T13:57:04.152664Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-09-23T13:57:04.194179Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
2020-09-23T13:57:34.288929Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2020-09-23T13:58:27.611679Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 2774
2020-09-23T13:58:27.622170Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-09-23T13:58:27.964705Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-09-23T13:58:28.067741Z 1 [Warning] [MY-010005] [Server] Skip re-populating collations and character sets tables in InnoDB read-only mode.
2020-09-23T13:58:28.073551Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2020-09-23T13:58:28.073930Z 2 [Warning] [MY-011018] [Server] Skip updating information_schema metadata in InnoDB read-only mode.
2020-09-23T13:58:28.075060Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010970] [Server] Skipped updating resource group metadata in InnoDB read only mode.
2020-09-23T13:58:28.075198Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010970] [Server] Skipped updating resource group metadata in InnoDB read only mode.
2020-09-23T13:58:28.117418Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-09-23T13:58:28.140691Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
2020-09-23T13:59:25.135939Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 8  user: 'dataintegra'.
2020-09-23T13:59:25.731711Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2020-09-23T14:00:42.499469Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 3039
2020-09-23T14:00:42.550347Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-09-23T14:00:43.007205Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-09-23T14:00:43.057449Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011096] [Server] No data dictionary version number found.
2020-09-23T14:00:43.057906Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2020-09-23T14:00:43.058212Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-09-23T14:00:43.583830Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2020-09-23T14:00:44.201857Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 3070
2020-09-23T14:00:44.211762Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-09-23T14:00:44.588604Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-09-23T14:00:44.592967Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011096] [Server] No data dictionary version number found.
2020-09-23T14:00:44.593261Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2020-09-23T14:00:44.593479Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

Lines:

```
2020-09-23T13:57:03.175203Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012197] [InnoDB] Unable to open './pharmiseu/visitscalendar.ibd'
2020-09-23T13:57:03.175349Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012197] [InnoDB] Unable to open './pharmiseu/specializations_prim.ibd'
```

contains names of my tables in db: `visitscalendar, specializations_prim` and `pharmiseu` is my DB.

In config `/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf` was inserted rows:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = 4
```

but in log is still:

```
│2020-09-23T20:28:19.427375Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)  (Ubuntu).                                                 │
│2020-09-23T20:28:19.966903Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 9601                                                      │
│2020-09-23T20:28:19.976957Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.                                                                                              │
│2020-09-23T20:28:20.230800Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.                                                                                                │
│2020-09-23T20:28:20.236029Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011096] [Server] No data dictionary version number found.                                                                                         │
│2020-09-23T20:28:20.236340Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.                                                                                           │
│2020-09-23T20:28:20.236550Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

[image: htop after 'sudo systemctl start mysql']

Comment: What is the error that's coming up, during `sqldump`?

Comment: try the solution using `mysqlfrm` utility https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16875/restore-table-from-frm-and-ibd-file

Comment: Is it InnoDB or MyISAM db?

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu its InnoDB. Ajay A. Its without errors - sqldump is empty. I have one question: Which approach is correct: 1. create new db (for example with name "test_db1" and after that copy content of old folder "test_db1" to new folder, or 2. don't create new db with name "test_db1" and only copy old folder "test_db1" to /var/lib/mysql ? In discussions i saw both and i don't know which access is correct. Thank you. –

Comment: And if i try approach 2: Only copy folder "test_db1" (with contend) to "new" folder /var/lib/mysql/test_db1 (after reinstall) and copy all ib* files, looks like that db isn't exist. I don't see this database in client (DBeaver) and i don't see any errors in "/var/log/mysql/error.log"

Comment: What's inside `/var/log/mysql/` ?

Comment: Did you copy those files while the database was running (as you say you _restarted_)? And is that location indeed the location where your newly installed database is storing its data?

Comment: Thanks for all replays. I updated my origin post with 12 steps which i am doing. 
Maybe / Perhaps i am doing something wrong and it is reason for my problems...

Comment: @IvoP Q1: yes, I copy that when server is stopped. Q2: probably yes, because when I create new database in DBeaver, folder is created here `/var/log/mysql/database_created_in_dbeaver`

Comment: Are old and new version of Mysql both the same? (not using mysql 5 datafiles for Mysql 8 server)

Comment: @IvoP i think that yes, because server was created before cca 4 months with OS Ubuntu Server 20.04 and on ubuntu 20.04 is default mysql server version 8.0. 
In my older snapshot was version 8.0.20 and now is a version 8.0.21. Do you mean that (.20 / .21) can it be a problem?

Comment: if I were to do this: Backup the mysql data directory; install a fresh Mysql server and use the same version number for it; backup the newly created data directory; copy the content of your old backup to the location where your database is expecting the data files. (all files and subdirs). Now start mysql.  Your old credentials should still be there.

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting as 'root' (MySQL root, no Ubuntu root)?

Are you using the correct Port?  3306 is typical, you seem to be using 33060?

Do not copy files or directories around.  A database is implemented as a directory *plus* some info in ibdata1 that you can't directly manipulate.  Likewise, a table is implemented with a small number of files, *plus* info buried in another file.

The only thing that will work is to copy the entire directory tree.

Comment: Q1: Hm, I don't know i am not mysql guru but i have created mysql root user and start "console" with `mysql -u root -p`. After login i see all databases without my "test_db1". Ownership of folder and files too is set to mysql:mysql. 

Q2: I think that isn't important because i am trying it directly in mysql console (SHOW DATABASES;).
**Do you think that backuped files can by corrupted?**

Comment: @lukassliacky - See my additions.

Comment: Rick, i restored my server from snapshot to mysql `Ver 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))` and when i copy only db folder and 'ib*` i don't see any errors but any database too. When i copied all folder with entire content of folder, my server cann't start and in log i see some information, but i didn't understand of that. 
I updated my origin post witn Update 4 and there you can see output in my logs.
Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Copy entire data directory **/var/lib/mysql** instead of **/var/lib/mysql/test_db1**. As there are lots of stuff in ibdata1 in case of innodb like table space etc. and  information schema keeps info of table.

Please copy entire data directory instead of particular database directory.

If you want to migrate only one database then dump and restore is good option.

Could you also please share output of

> show global variables like '%dir%';

Comment: thank you for your support. I updated my origin post with output of `show global variables like '%dir%';` and error log after copy entire dir `/var/lib/mysql/` to "new" `/var/lib/mysql/`

Comment: "No data dictionary version number found" This error occurs generally when mysql server versions are different in source and destination server

Comment: do you mean that it will be problem with 8.0.X too? On my "old" server was probably v 8.0.20 and on my current server is v 8.0.21

Comment: Please migrate with same version then upgrade.

Comment: i updated my origin post with some new information. (Server was restored to "older" version of db `mysql  Ver 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
`)

Comment: can you please share output of below command:
`ls -ld /var/run/mysqld` 
`ls -l /var/run/mysqld/*.lock`

Comment: hm, these files aren't exist: ```sudo su
root@xxxxx: ls -ld /var/run/mysqld
ls: cannot access '/var/run/mysqld': No such file or directory
root@xxxxx ls -l /var/run/mysqld/*.lock
ls: cannot access '/var/run/mysqld/*.lock': No such file or directory```

Comment: create this path **/var/run/mysqld** by `mkdir  /var/run/mysqld`.
and change ownership to mysql user and try to start

Comment: After full restore of server, creating of folder `/var/run/mysqld` and server start i see strange state.. After `sudo systemctl start mysql` is server probably starting (command `start mysql` is waiting). When i try in the second terminal `sudo systemctl status mysql` during this state, i see: `"Server startup in progress"`. This state take few minutes... Strange fact is that when i run `htop` i see some mysql processes (i add screenshot to end of my origin post). After maybe 5 - 10 min is process stopped and in status are shown message: `mysql.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.`

Answer (score 0):

This was a pain. I found my old script which every day downloading daily dumps and I can restore all my data from that. My problem still persist but it is not important right now.